# How to set view width according to another view's position?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, android-button

I have a `TextView` and a `Button` in an android XML layout(`TextView` is at left most side and `Button` is at right most side in the same line), as the text in `TextView` is dynamic so it should take a minimum width for some initial text to be visible. As width of devices changes the minimum width of `TextView` does not look good all the time.

For example if width of device becomes greater, then the minimum width alloted to the `TextView` would look so bad because it would not use more space available on the screen.

So what I want to do is to set the minimum width of `TextView` according to the position of `Button` present at the Right most side of the screen

Like minWidth = "leave this dp" form Button.

I hope you have understood it well if not then ask me more about it.
Seeking for attributes to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put button and textview inside linearlayout and set weight for textview and button according your requirement. it will set layout view according device screen size.

Comment: Yeah It solved my problem. It would be good if you let me know about weight little bit more.

Comment: set parent linear layout weightsum=3 and its inner textview weight=2 and button weight=1...then its view remain constant for all device screens..hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation put that `TextView` and `Button` inside that `LinearLayout`. Give weight of that `TextView` to `1` and set width to `0dp` and use `wrap_content` for Buttn's width

Code snippet

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"/>

       <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: we can not set layout_width as 0dp because it gives a error which says it is suspicious width so except that thing your answer is correct. Just remove the layout_width attribute then only I can accept your answer.

Comment: well @Andolasoft has given the answer first, so I have to accept his answer and as your answer is more clear I have clicked your answer as useful.

Comment: @DushyantSuthar no problem dude :)